# Convert an Autodesk VRED scene as SVF model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to show in FORGE Viewer a model created with Autodesk Inventor and edited (new colors & materials) with Autodesk VRED.

The native vp* formats are not supported by [Model Derivate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/): I've tried with a FBX file but the result in FORGE was horrible ;)

Have you some tips about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately VRED formats are not supported by the Forge Model Derivative service at the moment, so you'd have to find an intermediary format with as little quality (material definition) loss as possible. For example, if you could get your Inventor model into Fusion 360 (and perhaps customize its materials there), the materials would look much better in Forge Viewer as they would be rendered with the viewer's [PBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physically_based_rendering) shader. Go to https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io and choose one of the Fusion models (e.g., "Fusion Race Car") to see the shader in action.

Another option would be to apply your custom materials during runtime: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer.